# If value exists in CSV Papa Parse and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, papaparse

I am trying to search all fields in a CSV file and IF the value exists do one thing and IF NOT do another. I have Papa Parse reading the CSV file and logging to console the values on submit but for the life of me can not figure out the input value in the field and having find the value. I want to search all values/fields so if I enter a name or email or a number it would find it. Has to be exact match but not case sensitive. The CSV will not have to have a header but this one does so just treat them as entries to search by.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter a member email"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Submit</button>
```

Javascript

```
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;  
  
  var csv = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13566/names.csv";
    let results = [];  
  var csvData = Papa.parse(csv, {
    //header: true,
    download: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: response => {
      results = response.data;
      // You can access the data here
      console.log(results);
      //document.body.innerHTML += findEmailByName("exampleName2");
    }
  });
  function findEmailByName(name) {
    return results.filter(data => data.Name === name)[0].Email;
  }  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if(results[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should work');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

I also have a fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/8pbkqr0y/5/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Inside `response` you are getting 2 dimensional array as response so you need to use 2 loop one for outer array and other for inner array and get required value using `results[i][j]` .Also , if you don't want to include header in search start loop from `1`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val().toLowerCase();
  var isMatched = false;

  var csv = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13566/names.csv";
  let results = [];
  var csvData = Papa.parse(csv, {
    //header: true,
    download: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: response => {
      results = response.data;
      //outer array
      for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
        //inner array [0,1]
        for (var j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
          if (results[i][j].toLowerCase() === input2Val) {
          console.log(results[i][j].toLowerCase() +" -- "+ input2Val)
            isMatched = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (isMatched) {
        console.log('is matched and should work');
      } else {
        console.log('Is not matched! Error!');
      }
    }
  });



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter a member email" />
<button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: AWESOME! One question. How would i make this not case sensitive? I have tried adding results[i][j].toLowerCase() but get an error it is an invalid function. Works in fiddle but not when using in real page with jQuery.

Comment: Updated answer have a look.

Comment: I tried that but get the error. Uncaught TypeError: results[i][j].toLowerCase is not a function
    at Object.complete (local.js:216)
    at l.parseChunk (papaparse.min.js:7)
    at l._chunkLoaded (papaparse.min.js:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (papaparse.min.js:7)
complete @ local.js:216
parseChunk @ papaparse.min.js:7
_chunkLoaded @ papaparse.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ papaparse.min.js:7
load (async)
_readChunk @ papaparse.min.js:7
_nextChunk @ papaparse.min.js:7
stream @ papaparse.min.js:7
parse @ papaparse.min.js:7
saveBtn @ local.js:197
onclick @ (index):44

Comment: Can you try like this `results[i][j].toString().toLowerCase()` ?